# HTML5 Hyperlink a Table Data

Tags: javascript, html, css

how do i link hyperlink into a specific td ? Is it possible to do only with HTML and CSS without JS ?

```
<table width="10em" border="solid">
<tr>
<td><img src="logo.jpg" href="www.facebook.com"/></td>
<td><b>About</b><br />Us</td>
<td><b>Our</b><br />Menu</td>
<td><b>Our</b><br />Location</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td><a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="logo.jpg" /></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
<td><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="logo.jpg" /></a></td>
```

because `img` `tag` doesn't support `href` attribute